# ngbTypeahead with *ngFor directive

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I have one input field inside *ngFor which will execute 4 times.
When i am clicking on one of the input field, ngbTypeahead suggestions is getting open for all four input fields.

Here is my code:

.html

```
<div *ngFor="let number of [0,1,2,3,4];let i=index">
  <label for="typeahead-focus">Search for a state:</label>
<input type="text"
                                        class="form-control border-bottom  chBd border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0"
                                        aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)"  
                                        [ngbTypeahead]="search"
                                        (focus)="focus$.next($event.target.value)"
                                        (click)="click$.next($event.target.value)"
                                        #instance="ngbTypeahead"
                                        />
</div>
```

.ts

```
import {Component, ViewChild, QueryList, ViewChildren} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbTypeahead} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {Observable, Subject, merge} from 'rxjs';
import {debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, filter, map} from 'rxjs/operators';

const states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska'];

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-typeahead-focus',
  templateUrl: './typeahead-focus.html',
  styles: [`.form-control { width: 300px; }`]
})
export class NgbdTypeaheadFocus {
  model: any;

  @ViewChild('instance') instance: NgbTypeahead;
  focus$ = new Subject<string>();
  click$ = new Subject<string>();

  search = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(debounceTime(200), distinctUntilChanged());
    const clicksWithClosedPopup$ = this.click$.pipe(filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen()));
    const inputFocus$ = this.focus$;

    return merge(debouncedText$,inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(
      map(term => (term === '' ? states
        : states.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 10))
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try isolating label and input to an independent component and listing out that directive through *ngFor? Also, if that doesn't help please make small stackblitz demo so we can check.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: Make a new component that would have html with this label and input with #instance="ngbTypeahead". It will isolate scope and that trigger on #instance won't be visible to other components, it will be accessible in that scope only. In that way, it will open ngbTypeahead only for input related in that component. Combining with @Input() and @Output() decoratiors from inside that component, you should be able to make data flow for that component. Please create a small demo so i can fork it and give you a better look on how it should look like.

Comment: Okay. I will try to create a plunker.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61330879/angular-9-more-than-one-ngb-typeahead-in-one-form/61342995#61342995

Answer (score 0):

** HTML **

```
<div *ngFor="let number of [0,1,2,3,4];let i=index">
  <label for="typeahead-focus">Search for a state:</label>
<input type="text"
                                        class="form-control border-bottom  chBd border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0"
                                        aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)"  
                                        

[ngbTypeahead]="searchTypeHead(i)"

                                         (focus)="focus$.next({ value:$any($event).target.value, index:i})"
  (click)="click$.next({ value:$any($event).target.value, index:i})"
                                        #instance="ngbTypeahead"
                                        />
</div>
```

** TS **

```
  export class NgbdTypeaheadFocus {
    model: any;
  
    @ViewChildren('instance') instance: QueryList<NgbTypeahead>;
    focus$ = new Subject<any>();
    click$ = new Subject<any>();
    
    search = (text$: Observable<string>, index) => {
      const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(debounceTime(200), distinctUntilChanged());
      const clicksWithClosedPopup$ = this.click$.pipe(filter((item) => !this.instance.toArray()[index].isPopupOpen() && item.index == index), map(item => item.value));
    const inputFocus$ = this.focus$.pipe(filter((item) => item.index === index), map(item => item.value));
  
      return merge(debouncedText$,inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(
        map(term => (term === '' ? states
          : states.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 10))
      );
    }

    searchTypeHead(index): OperatorFunction<string, readonly string[]> {
        return (text$: Observable<string>) => {
          return this.search(text$, index)
        }
      }
  }
```

** REF **
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qdxcvn?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftypeahead-focus.html,src%2Fapp%2Ftypeahead-focus.ts