# Angular 9: More than one ngb-typeahead in one form?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, viewchild

I am using the [NgbTypeahead component from NG-Boostrap 6.0.3](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples) in my Angular 9 app. The first one works fine, but my form has quite a few.

Do I need to add a separate ViewChild and a separate search function for each one of them?  Or am I missing something?  Can someone point me to an example with more than one?

For reference, here's a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cnqwcn) with just the one.

Comment: Yes, you need two "search"s and two ViewChilds

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid of that.

Comment: well, sorry my quickly comment, of course you can use an unique search function (imposible is nothing) see my answer and apologies my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, really my comment is NOT correct, imagine you has 2 ngbTypeHead You need that focus$ and click$ was an array, for this, you can use map, some like

```
focus$ = [0,1].map(_=>new Subject<string>());
click$ = [0,1].map(_=>new Subject<string>());
```

Well, you can also too make some like (I use a fool array and map) but it is the same than:

```
focus$ = [new Subject<string>(),new Subject<string>()];
```

I use an array to the model

```
model: any[]=[];
```

And change the searchFunction that received as parameters: an index, a instance and a term (the index is necesary to make reference to the subjects

```
searchType(index,instance, text$) {
    return (text$: Observable<string>) => {
      const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(
        debounceTime(200),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      );
      const clicksWithClosedPopup$ = this.click$[index].pipe(
        filter(() => !instance.isPopupOpen())
      );
      const inputFocus$ = this.focus$[index];

      return merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(
        map(term =>
          (term === ""
            ? states
            : states.filter(
                v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1
              )
          ).slice(0, 10)
        )
      );
    };
  }
```

Then, the only we need is change our ngbTypeahead

```
  <input
        ...
  [(ngModel)]="model[index]"
  [ngbTypeahead]="searchType(i,instance,$text)"
  (focus)="focus$[i].next($any($event).target.value)"
  (click)="click$[i].next($any($event).target.value)"
  #instance="ngbTypeahead"
  >
```

You can see an example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gzqtgs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**Update** if we need differents data, we can improve the function search passing the "data", so, if we add a new parameter to search:

```
searchType(index,instance, data,text$) { //<--pass "data"
    return (text$: Observable<string>) => {
      const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(
        debounceTime(200),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      );
      const clicksWithClosedPopup$ = this.click$[index].pipe(
        filter(() => !instance.isPopupOpen())
      );
      const inputFocus$ = this.focus$[index];

      return merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(
        map(term =>
          (term === ""
            ? data          //<--here use data
            : data.filter(  //<--here use data too
                v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1
              )
          ).slice(0, 10)
        )
      );
    };
  }
```

We can change the call and write:

```
[ngbTypeahead]="searchType(i,instance,states,$text)"
```

Another option is, according to the "index" search in one or another array, so the function becomes like

```
searchType(index,instance, text$) { 
    const data=index==0?states:this.fruits; //<--the data according the index
    return (text$: Observable<string>) => {
      const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(
        debounceTime(200),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      );
      const clicksWithClosedPopup$ = this.click$[index].pipe(
        filter(() => !instance.isPopupOpen())
      );
      const inputFocus$ = this.focus$[index];

      return merge(debouncedText$, inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(
        map(term =>
          (term === ""
            ? data          //<--here use data
            : data.filter(  //<--here use data too
                v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1
              )
          ).slice(0, 10)
        )
      );
    };
  }
```

Comment: Clever solution, thanks.  The part that has me stumped is that the data source (here, "states") for the menu is inside the search function. Obviously, my menus each have a different array source for their menu items.  I would think it would be best to pass this from the html instances:  this menu is state, this menu is countries etc.

Comment: you can pass to the function search as argument the data. I updated my answer and the stackblitz, true it's an "ugly hack" how pass the data in the stackblitz, I use a ternary operator because only has 2 ngbTypeHead. Another function is, according the "index", search in an array or not