# I want to use ngb typehead dynamically but when i click on any one it is opening all the typeheads

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

following is the HTML code which has the ngb typehead input how i it will work seperately for all the inputs have tried but not resolved
HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let number of [0,1,2,3,4];let i=index">
    <label for="typeahead-focus">Search for a state:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control border-bottom border-top-0 border-right-0 
    border-left-0" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)" [ngbTypeahead]="search" 
    (focus)="focus$.next($event.target.value)" (click)="click$.next($event.target.value)" 
    #instance="ngbTypeahead"/>
</div>
```

this is typescript code

```
TS

const states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska'];
  
model1: any;
@ViewChild('instance') instance: NgbTypeahead;
focus$ = new Subject<string>();
click$ = new Subject<string>();

search = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    const debouncedText$ = text$.pipe(debounceTime(200), distinctUntilChanged());
    const clicksWithClosedPopup$ = this.click$.pipe(filter(() => !this.instance.isPopupOpen()));
    const inputFocus$ = this.focus$;
    return merge(debouncedText$,inputFocus$, clicksWithClosedPopup$).pipe(
      map(term => (term === '' ? states
        : states.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)).slice(0, 10))
    );
  }
```

Comment: All 5 `<input>`s use the same Observables (`focus$` and `click$`) and template reference variable (`instance`).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61330879/angular-9-more-than-one-ngb-typeahead-in-one-form/61342995#61342995